# all the other boxes vs the other boxes

Tags: comparative-constructions

For example, we have some boxes (A, B, C, D) in the room...

If the second sentence is grammatically correct, what is the difference?

> Box A is bigger than **all the other boxes**.
>
> Box A is bigger than **the other boxes**.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a room full of hundreds of boxes, if you say "This box (A) is bigger than the other boxes.", there might be another box that you didn't notice, that's as big as A or bigger. If you say "A is bigger than **all** the other boxes", you are making an emphatic statement, claiming to be sure that A is biggest.

In your example, with four boxes, the "all" is unnecessary emphasis.